# How to clear textbox when all checkboxes are unchecked in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

[image]

how should I clear textboxes, when all checkboxes are unchecked.

```
    private void qualitySetupDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        DataGridView data = this.qualitySetupDataGridView;
        int CurrentRow = data.CurrentRow.Index;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in data.Rows) {
            object cell = Row.Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue;

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(cell) == false) {
                textBox1.Clear();


            }
```

More code added. I have added more code in order to make this more easier to understand.

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue) == true)
 {

EndsPerInch = double.Parse(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                Sum = Sum + EndsPerInch;
                count++;
                Average = Sum / count;
                FinalValue = Math.Round(Average, 2);
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(FinalValue);

            }

else if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue) == false)
            {
                EndsPerInch = double.Parse(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                Sum = Sum - EndsPerInch;
                count--;
                Average = Sum / count;
                FinalValue = Math.Round(Average, 2);
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(FinalValue);
         //       textBox1.Clear();

                count = 0;
                Sum = 0;
                EndsPerInch = 0;
                Average = 0;
                FinalValue = 0;


            }
```

This is from Top to bottom Code in Cell Content Click of DataGridView.

**SystemFormatException:**

[image]

Comment: We need more information how the databinding is setup. Please show us code.

Comment: added code. check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  bool shouldClearTextBox = true;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in data.Rows)
  {
    object cell = Row.Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue;
    // If the particular checkbox isn't cleared, shouldClearTextBox is set to false
    shouldClearTextBox &= !Convert.ToBoolean(cell);
  }
  if (shouldClearTextBox)
    textBox1.Clear();
```

Comment: &= is a boolean expression. It requires both arguments to be true, to return true, otherwise it return false. Actually it's & thats is the boolean operator, and &= is the same as res = var1 & var2;

Comment: I'm getting System Format Exception. Plus I added more code on the original post.

Comment: Ok, I just contribute to your existing code, without running it. Could you post entire exception?

Comment: added in my original post.

Comment: Okay, not easy to figure without your full code. Have you verified that Convert.ToBoolean(cell) works?

Comment: You should also add a null check for cell before using it

Comment: Ok il try into my original post, it's not allowing me to add all of it.

Comment: where should the null check goes?

Comment: If you read my contributed code as conceptual, it should guide you to success. The idea is to make sure all checkboxes are selected, by using the boolean operator & , which requires both left and right hand var to be true in order to return true. This can be accomplished in various ways.

Comment: If you're using visual studio, it should show you the exact line where the error goes.

Comment: If you want me to solve you're problem, you'll have to post entire code base. I guess the code you posted so far is code inside some event handlers? (The first one excluded)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71942/discussion-between-s22-and-fawad).

Comment: Solved!
Thanks.

Problem was: I Edited "Checked Box Column" and Set its True value to something "True or False" maybe in CAPS" 

changed truth value to "true"

moved code to the bottom of the rest of the code. it worked. 

`if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue) == true){  do this } `     `else if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.Rows[CurrentRow].Cells[5].EditedFormattedValue) == false){  do this} ` then your code.