# C# display value in textboxes when checkboxes are checked in DataGridView and clear when unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a checkbox column in datagridview, where if I check the checkbox, the cell values will be parse in to textboxes & combobox and unchecked will clear the all the textboxes & combobox.

I have achieved the above description, the problem is when i checked it from bottom to top order, the textboxes value won't change. It will remain the same to the first checked.

As my snippet below, textbox should display 'AZI' since i checked it after 'FRAN', but it still show 'FRAN'. But if the checked order is 'AZI' then 'FRAN', it will behave correctly.

[image: snippet]

I have referred this post [How to clear textbox when all checkboxes are unchecked in DataGridView C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781658/how-to-clear-textbox-when-all-checkboxes-are-unchecked-in-datagridview-c-sharp)

And below is my codes so far,

```
private void datagridview1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            bool unSel = true;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridview1.Rows)
            {
                DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["ckbox"];
                bool isSel = (bool)chk.EditedFormattedValue;
                object cell = row.Cells["ckbox"].EditedFormattedValue;
                unSel &= !Convert.ToBoolean(cell);

                if (isSel)
                {
                    combobox1.Text = row.Cells["combobox1"].Value.ToString();
                    textbox1.Text = row.Cells["textbox1"].Value.ToString();
                    textbox2.Text = row.Cells["textbox2"].Value.ToString();
                    textbox3.Text = row.Cells["textbox3"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            if (unSel)
            {
                textbox1.Clear();
                cbDoctorList.Text = "";
                textbox2.Clear();
                textbox3.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Appreciate your helps on this!

Comment: Your description is not really clear. When I select a checkbox, what text should be in the textbox? When I uncheck, should only the textbox in this line be unchecked?

Comment: Is this Winforms? If yes, please add the "winforms" tag

Comment: @Presi when checkbox is checked, the value from the datagridview cell will be parse into the texbox1,2,3 and combobox1. if unchecked, all the value will be clear. In the image i only show 1 textbox as example, but all 4 will behave same

Comment: You iterate all items every time you check a checkbox. I think you could find out if the cell is checked or not with you event args.

Answer (score 0):

When you toggle a checkbox in a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` it normally puts the `CurrentCell` into edit mode. The new value isn't *committed* to the cell until the `DataGridView` leaves edit mode one way or another.

You could try ending the edit immediately when a checkbox toggles. See if it helps to add this code first in your click handler method.

```
void datagridview1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    if (dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        dataGridView.EndEdit();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

I [tested](https://github.com/IVSoftware/datagridview-with-checkboxes.git) this answer using your test case where the checked order is "FRAN" then "AZI" and it works as expected with the minimal sample shown below.

[image: screenshot]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows= false;
        dataGridView.DataSource = Items;
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "AZI" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "FRAN" });
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Item.Selected)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Item.Name)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        dataGridView.CellContentClick += onCellContentClick;
    }

    private void onCellContentClick(object? sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (dataGridView.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        {
            dataGridView.EndEdit();

            Item item = Items[e.RowIndex];
            textBoxLast.Text = item.Selected ? item.Name : string.Empty;
            textBoxAll.Text =
                string.Join(
                    ",",
                    Items.Where(_=>_.Selected).Select(_ => _.Name));
        }
    }
    BindingList<Item> Items = new BindingList<Item>();
}
class Item
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```